# Deploy Build from Separate Job in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins, continuous-deployment

I have anywhere from 5 to 15 jobs in jenkins (varies from week to week) that deploy essentially the same code to our environments, but with different configurations. Is there a way to have one job do the building and separate jobs to do the deploying?

I have seen people suggest a custom workspace, but I have other builds I still want to deploy normally.

I'm still somewhat new to jenkins, I'm hoping there's some convention/best practice for this situation before I delve into hard coding the paths.

Comment: A parameterized build might let you reduce the number of distinct builds you need to create

Comment: That's what we're doing currently and is how we can use the same job for trunk, branch 1, branch 2, etc. We have a build profile for each setup, which will do xdt transforms. This is actually becoming a mess though as we keep having to modify the .sln and .csproj files with xdt transforms to boot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to build your code one time with a dedicated job and next, deploy multiple configurations using other Jenkins jobs?

If your build job delivers some artifacts (war, zip, ...), you can archive these artifacts (at the build job level). And next, use the [Copy Artifact Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin) to get these artifacts in your deployment jobs (it's a build step).

The other solution is to archive the built workspace (at the build job level), and next uses this archive as a SCM source for your deployment jobs. You can use the [Clone Workspace SCM Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Clone+Workspace+SCM+Plugin) for that.

Comment: Is it normal convention that a build created, be archived and then imported into the second job? Right now, since I know it will be in the same folder, I hardcoded the path and invoked the deploy.cmd with overriding parameters passed in so it will deploy to the separate locations.

Comment: It's a little bit of a pain, but I'll also have to put together a script to modify some of our configurations via a powershell or shell script to search and replace the other configurations as well.

Comment: For my job, I used this solution to share a workspace build on Linux with another job running on Windows (to build a MSI package). This is not a "classic" workflow :)

Answer (score 0):

better use a multi-configuration job with axis as deployment types(5-15). even you can restrict the choice of deployment type by build parameterised.

Even you have a freedom of choosing customized or common work space

you can configure build code as a upstream project for deployment job.